# Angular2 understand logic

Tags: angular

A service with onRefresh$ event

```js
private onRefresh = new Subject<ElementItemValueModel>();
onRefresh$ = this.onRefresh.asObservable();
```

Component with subscription

```js
constructor(
    private dataService: DataService,
    private ngZone: NgZone,
) {
    this.dataService.onRefresh$.subscribe(()=> {
        this.doRefresh(this.dataService.findElement(this.elementId));
    });
}

doRefresh(element) {
    console.log(this.element.name, element.name);
    this.element = element || this.element;
    console.log(this.element.name, JSON.stringify(this.element) == JSON.stringify(element));

    //this.ngZone.run(() => {});
}
```

Console output

```js
undefined "XXX"
XXX true
```

View not refresh

If uncomment **this.ngZone.run(() => {});** or **click** on clickable item in view - view refresh

Question: why not refresh automaticaly?

Comment: Is the changeDetection of the component OnPush, oder default?

Comment: @philipooo default (not declared)